# Binding MVVM with (only) some columns autogenerated from a collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, telerik, radgridview

I have a collection of objects which I want to bind to a RadGridView (from the toolkit telerik). The class of the objects is looking like that (minimum code needed to understand) where I have 1 property and 1 array of values which :

```
public class AttributeEntry : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Code { get; set; }
        private string[] _values;
        public string[] Values
        {
            get { return _values; }
            set { _values = value; }
        }
        public string this[int index]
        {
            get { return _values[index]; }
            set
            {
                _values[index] = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(Binding.IndexerName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

Is someone know a (simple) way, using the patern MVVM,  to have a RadGridView with some columns defined (in my case corresponding to the 'Code' property) and some columns "autogenerated" with each columns corresponding to the elements of a collection (in my case the elements of the array 'Values". If I have 7 values in my collection, I should have 7 "autogenerated" columns)?

Comment: Is the number of elements in Values going to be dynamic?

Comment: No. All the AttributeEntry object will have the same number of elements in the Values array. It's defined with an application configuration parameter (for the moment it's 150 values but tomorrow it could change...)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are binding your `RadGridView` to a collection of `AttributeEntry`.

In that case, implement `ITypedList` on your collection. You can use `ITypedList` to return virtual `PropertyDescriptor` whose `GetValue` and `SetValue` methods use the array

Answer (score 1):

For anybody who is trying to implement this, declare your class as an expandoobject this a flexible class structure with implements INotifyPropertyChanged and you can define the properties as required in code.

On the telerik raddatagrid bind the itemsource to a collection of the expandoobjects and set AutoGenerateColumns to true.

If you want to tailor the columns based upon the contents of the expandoobject then use the AutoGeneratingColumn event, this is fired for each column generate, if you define your column controls as datatemplates you can access them in the code behind and assign them too the cell template.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `RadGridView` but for a normal `DataGrid` you can either set the `AutoGenerateColumns` Property to `true` to auto generate columns based on its data binding or `false` to create your columns based on your code.

<strike>In your case, I think you have to set `AutoGenerateColumns` Property to `false` and define your columns by yourself to combine both (elements of your collection and the Code property).</strike>

**EDIT:**

Just checked the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratecolumns.aspx) :

> Explicitly declared column fields can
>   be used in combination with
>   automatically generated column fields.
>   When both are used, explicitly
>   declared column fields are rendered
>   first, followed by the automatically
>   generated column fields.

Comment: Yes, it's what I've thought first. I've tried this solution but :

Comment: Yes, it's what I've thought first. I've tried this solution but :
1. It's not very MVVM compliant :( 
2. I didn't found why but the first values of the "Values" collections was not displayed... it's seems that the binding was done before the Values where affected (for the frist values) which souldn't be the case!

Comment: I think @Bolu was in the right direction, but no all the way.

The AttributeEntry object looks like a strange translation of some other concrete data source.

If the underlying source of the data returns an object with all these properties, then the AutoGenerated columns for the RadGridView will work as they were designed to and automatically create a column for each property.

Is the source data really unstructured?